# How can I use react to replace Twig templates

Tags: php, reactjs, twig

I hope this is the correct forum to ask this question, apologies if it's not.

We are considering switching to reactjs for our framework for an existing product. Currently we are using several twig templates to render a different view based on the client that is using the product. So we have something similar to the following:

```
-templates
    -customerType_one
     -- calculator.html.twig
     -- stopwatch.html.twig
     -- calendar.html.twig
    -customerType_two
     -- calculator.html.twig
     -- stopwatch.html.twig
     -- calendar.html.twig
```

Before we make the switch I wanted to understand how react could be used to replace those templates. I understand how every view in react is essentially a template and it's understandable from a surface level but how would it work in my existing circumstance. Would I have the same structure but now on the client side with just different react files for every template type?

Or is the same tempalte manipulated based on data given to template? How does traditional templating work in react?